# Automatically updating/duplicating a table in Microsoft Access with VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, entity-relationship

Back again! So I am currently trying to programmatically have a table (Table2) update after a button is pressed. I would like for Table2 to resemble exactly another table (Table1). I'm going through this effort because Access does not allow double relationships and I have need to create one. I will therefore have two tables containing all the contact info.

I tried deleting Table2 and then creating another copy of Table1 and saving it as Table2. This would have worked is Microsoft Access didn’t throw an error because I am deleting a Table that has established relationships. So I then tried to programmatically delete and then create the appropriate relationships. However, this turns out to be a tedious exercise. A little too tedious for my taste.

My next thought is to create an append query that automatically looks for differences between the two tables and updates Table2 accordingly. The problem is that I have no idea how to structure the SQL statement for such an append query. Also is there an easier way to do this using VBA that I am missing? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's a "double relationship"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to go to all this trouble. You **can** have double relationships in MS Access. Simply add the table as many times as you need it to the relationship design window, you will get Table1, Table1_1, Table1_2 and so on, but they are all just aliases for Table1. You can now add self-joins and as many relationships as you need.

Like so:

```
*People*
PersonID        *People_1*
ManagerID -- >   PersonID
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are able to append from `Table1` to `Table2` without running afoul of any relationship.  If that is true, you can empty out `Table2`, then append all the rows from `Table1`.

```
Dim cn As Object
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
cn.Execute "DELETE FROM Table2"
```

If Table2 includes an autonumber field, reset its seed value.

```
cn.Execute "ALTER TABLE Table2" & vbCrLf & _
"ALTER COLUMN autonum_fld COUNTER(1, 1)"
```

Then do the append ...

```
cn.Execute _
"INSERT INTO Table2 (autonum_fld, text_field, long_int_field)" & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT autonum_fld, text_field, long_int_field" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM Table1;"
```

... or if the two table structures are identical, you don't even have to list the field names ...

```
cn.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2" & vbCrLf & _ 
"SELECT *" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM Table1;"
```

And finally ...

```
Set cn = Nothing
```

AFAICT, that could work.  However, I don't understand the background details of your question, for example "*Access does not allow double relationships*".  So I may be completely off the mark.